# bx slider is not working properly with rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, bxslider

I am using gem 'bxslider-rails' in one of my project . i  am following all the proper steps to use it according to its github page .i am using bxslider in my home page and it is working perfectly fine.

but the issue is when i move from home page to other page and come back to home page then bx slider is not working and in place of that all the slide element are views as list .and when i refresh my page it works properly .

Any suggestion to solve this issue. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

try using rel="external" to the other page then back to main also using rel="external"